# How can I use post step in Jenkins pipeline with kubernetes plugin

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I try to use the post steps with the Jenkins kubernetes plugin. Does anyone has an idea?

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'post' found among steps
```

My pipeline:

```
podTemplate(
        label: 'jenkins-pipeline',
        cloud: 'minikube',
        volumes: [
                hostPathVolume(mountPath: '/var/run/docker.sock', hostPath: '/var/run/docker.sock'),
        ]) {

    node('jenkins-pipeline') {
        stage('test') {
            container('maven') {
                println 'do some testing stuff'
            }
        }

        post {
            always {
                println "test"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of this writing, [`Post` is only supported in declarative pipelines](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-44160).

You could have a look at their [declarative example](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin/blob/master/examples/declarative.groovy) if you absolutely must use `post`.

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    kubernetes {
      //cloud 'kubernetes'
      label 'mypod'
      containerTemplate {
        name 'maven'
        image 'maven:3.3.9-jdk-8-alpine'
        ttyEnabled true
        command 'cat'
      }
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage('Run maven') {
      steps {
        container('maven') {
          sh 'mvn -version'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: whats the alternative solution without post?

Comment: Probably try/catch -- see https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#flow-control

Comment: The example doesn't show use of post {}.. ohh ok OP is using scripted pipeline not declarative.

Comment: @mghicks please show how to use post in your example.

Comment: @Sam sorry, I don't have an easy way to test this now, but it should be just as in the doc at https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post or your example.

Answer (score 2):

This example shows how to use the post step using the Kubernetes plugin:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    kubernetes {
      label "my-test-pipeline-${BUILD_NUMBER}"
      containerTemplate {
        name "my-container"
        image "alpine:3.15.0"
        command "sleep"
        args "99d"
      }
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage('Stage 1') {
      steps {
        container('my-container') {
          sh '''
            set -e
            echo "Hello world!"
            sleep 10
            echo "I waited"

            echo "forcing a fail"
            exit 1
          '''
        }
      }
    }
  }
  post {
    unsuccessful {
      container('my-container') {
        sh '''
          set +e
          echo "Cleaning up stuff here"
        '''
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: does this really work? In my test, the k8s agent is destroyed at the end of the stages. I am unable to use it in post activities..

Comment: nevermind I found my issue. For anyone interested by a similar scenario : If you start with agent none and create the k8s agent later, make sure your post activities is just below the stages that uses the K8s agent and not the one that use 'agent none'

Comment: In my case, the agent/container is indeed destroyed, but another one is spun up to do the post steps.